# Pass values from php array as param in UNION query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to pass values from array as individual parameter in a query and use them as below

```
Array
(
    [0] => some
    [1] => text
)
```

I want this kind of function

```
public function getData($some,$text)
{
$sql = " select * from table where field1 = '{$some}' OR field3 = {$some}      ";
$union = " UNION ";
$sql = " select * from table where field2 = '{$text}' or field4 = {$text}  ";
}
```

Note: The array may have Nth number of index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
public function getQuery($dataArray) {
    $queryArray = array();
    foreach($dataArray as $data) {
        $query = "SELECT * from `table`";
        $conditionArray = array();
        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            $conditionArray[] = "`$key` = `$value`";
        }
        if (!empty ($conditionArray)) {
            $query .= " WHERE ". implode(" OR ", $conditionArray);
        }
        $queryArray[] = $query;
    }
    return implode(" UNION ", $queryArray);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Akshat it worked....but in my case I do not require the second loop. There is only a single array.

Answer (score 0):

Since your query is made on the same column, try the [IN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator to skip UNIONS:

```
select * from table where field1 IN (val1,val2....)
```

Then you can pass an array as the parameter

```
public function getData($data)
{
    if(!empty($data)) {
        return " select * from table where field1 = ".implode(",",$data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ka_lin but I want union and the fields are different. I have edited my question also